# How to convert 1/2 to 2 in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

what I need is that I ask the user to input something like 1/2

ex: `i=input("Input the half; if one-sixteenth enter 1/16" )`

what I need is to take 16 out of 1/16 and use it for calculations.

in math we can easily use 1/(1/16), but in python I do get a data type error when trying to asign and do the calculations using the fractional value like this,

Any help is highly apprecitated

Comment: What error do you get

Comment: show the actual code that raised an error and the actual error please.([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I'm assuming python doesn't much like division with a `str`?

Comment: um... `"1/2"` can't be cast to an `int` although it can be cast to a [`fractions.Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html)

Comment: Input returns a string. Strings can be split, In this case, the string representation of a fraction can be split into numerator and denominator at the / sign.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but Python does understand fractions - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

One benefit of this is that you check for invalid input by catching the `ValueError` exception.

```
from fractions import Fraction


f = None

while(f is None):
    n = input("Enter a fraction: ")

    try:
        f = Fraction(n)
    except ValueError:
        print(n, "isn't a valid fraction")

print(f)
print(float(f))
print(f.denominator)

# input 1/6 gives:
# 1/6
# 0.166666666667
# 6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i=input("Input the half; if one-sixteenth enter 1/16" )
k = i.split("/")
```

k[1] will be the denominator

and

```
int(k[1])
```

will be it as a number

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate x = 1/16; and then calculate y = 1/x. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fractions` module. But I if understand your question correctly, your user enters `1/16` in this fraction form and you want the `16` out of it.

```
x = input("Fraction: ") # Fraction: 1 / 16 or 1/16 or 1/ 16, whatever
n = int(x.split("/")[-1].strip()) # 16 (int)
```

If it's now what you want then please comment.